# Are there any algorithms for determining the format of binary data through statistical analysis?

Tags: algorithm, statistics, data-analysis

I was wondering if there are any algorithms or techniques that can be used to determine (make an educated guess, really) what type of data are represented by an unknown binary segment.

For example, I recently came [this post](http://blogs.technet.com/b/steve_lamb/archive/2007/06/05/it-s-easy-to-find-encrypted-areas-of-hard-disk-as-illustrated-by-diskscape-drive-analysis.aspx) on Steve Lamb's blog and I found the concept of the DiskScape tool interesting. I was wondering exactly what they might be analyzing, and how they were analyzing it, in order to make their determinations (and graphs).

I was also curious as to whether a similar technique could be expanded to analyze the format/contents of data as well.

Comment: if the data  is not compressed then yes up to some point...  for example used numbers can determine if it is a text or not, histogram can even detect used language if you have tables per each used language and big enough chunk of data. for other types of data images,graphs,tables you could try to visualize DCT,DFT ,and image in 1/2/3D to see if some sense is there or compare to predefined examples (the dimensionality can be detected also by examining distance between patterns) ... you can search for usual IDs like `MZ`,`RIFF`,... reliable method for any data is improbable at least